# DataTables: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined (HTML DOM sourced)

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, datatables

I had my DataTables working correctly (for the most part) for a Job Board, but recently I noticed that I am receiving errors and the filtering and sorting functionality is not appearing on my webpage. I know that this is a common issue, but I have not seen any documentation for if someone is using DOM for their data source.

I've looked at a lot of the other queries here on StackOverflow as well as the DataTables FAQs: 
https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined
https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-adata-is-undefined

Which all talk about if you are using AJAX to load your dataset, which I am not.
According to DataTables.net for me to use the DOM as my source it should be as easy as putting

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

In my Javascript, and including these 2 library files:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

According to:

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html

Here is what I currently have:

Header.php:

```
<!--NEED FULL JS NOT SLIM-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- MDBootstrap Datatables  -->

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

DOM/Page in WordPress:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="jobBoardTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th id="date" class="first">Date Posted</th>
<th id="region">Region</th>
<th id="country">Country</th>
<th id="city">City</th>
<th id="academic-field">Academic Field</th>
<th id="position">Position(s) Name</th>
<th id="job-start-date">Job Start Date</th>
<th id="app-close-date">Application Closing Date</th>
<th id="details">Job Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="first">9-October-2019</td>
<td>North America</td>
<td>Canada</td>
<td>Toronto</td>
<td>The Faculty of Information and the Department of Statistical Sciences - University of Toronto</td>
<td>Associate Professor, Statistical Information</td>
<td>1 July 2020</td>
<td>25 November 2019</td>
<td><a class="btn btn-default" href="https://chroniclevitae.com/jobs/0000507495-01">Details</a></td>
</tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Footer.php:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function () {
  if($('#jobBoardTable')){
      //$.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD-MMM-YYYY' );
     // $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'DD MMM YYYY' );
      $('#jobBoardTable').DataTable();
      $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
  }
});</script>
```

I've also attempted with removing my if statement in the footer with no avail.

I exepect DataTables to function and to see a Search box, up and down arrows next to each table header, and pagination.

What I am actually getting are these, the first is a warning, the second is an error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Ma (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:37:72)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:30:42)
    at https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:1326
    at Function.map (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:3169)
    at w.fn.init.map (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:1294)
    at pa (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:30:22)
    at e (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:106:15)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js:106:198)
    at Function.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:2573)
    at w.fn.init.each (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2:1240) undefined
```

Then followed by this error once everything is loaded:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Ma (jquery.dataTables.min.js:37)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:30)
    at jquery-3.3.1.min.js:formatted:72
    at Function.map (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:formatted:171)
    at w.fn.init.map (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:formatted:71)
    at pa (jquery.dataTables.min.js:30)
    at e (jquery.dataTables.min.js:106)
    at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:106)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:formatted:137)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:formatted:68)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Works for me.. which makes me think that your error is from somewhere else? Could be because I only had one row of data to test.

Comment: @Lian You're right. It works. I stupidly had my data messed up with 2 <tr> tags right next to each other and only 1 closed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure how to close a question without having an answer.

Essentially, be sure to double check your DOM (that was my issue).

Having extraneous `<tr>` tags breaks the data set so it isn't read properly.